# How to use placeholder with inputs in table with ngFor Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an array

```
 public example = [['hallo', 'fruit', 'rose'], ['apple','book']]
```

And I want to make a table of inputs, which values depends on which part do I use now 
`http://localhost:4200/app?part=1` and

```
http://localhost:4200/app?part=2
```

I get this information in my component

```
   this.part = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['part'];
```

What I want to have is table of inputs like this for first part [image: Part1 example] 
and table of inputs like this
 [image]
if I have second part.

I tried this code

```
      <table>
//choose 0 or 1 array in example array (this works!)
        <tr *ngFor="let a of example[part-1]">
          <td><input> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

My problem is that if I try to insert placeholder or ngFor to inputs I don't get my result...how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super clear to me what you are trying to achieve but you could try with:

```
  <table>
    //choose 0 or 1 array in example array (this works!)
    <tr *ngFor="let a of example[part-1]">
      <td><input [placeholder]="a"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

This would give you inputs with the placeholder "hello", "apple", etc..

If what you want is each input has only a letter placeholder then just add another *ngFor on the td

```
  <table>
    //choose 0 or 1 array in example array (this works!)
    <tr *ngFor="let a of example[part-1]">
      <td *ngFor="let b of a.split('')"><input [placeholder]="b"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```